# sort numerically inline, no by sorting the rows

Tags: bash, sorting

I am familiar with the sort command and the -n flag to sort a file numerically in linux. However, the sorting is done by rearranging the rows in the file. I am looking for a way to sort the numbers in all rows without altering the row number, instead the position of the entries in each row. For example, for:

```
1 62 83 3 
26 23 12 503 1
9 7 7 6 120
```

The output should look like:

```
1 3 62 83 
1 12 23 26 503 
6 7 7 9 120
```

My input file will have rows with different number of columns and the columns are space separated always. I will also often have repeated numbers in each row. Is there a way for sort, or a similar command to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `sort` is a program and it's not specific to Linux, not even part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for [PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" }
    { split($0,a); c=0; for (i in a) $(++c)=a[i]; print }
' file
1 3 62 83
1 12 23 26 503
6 7 7 9 120
```

otherwise you could write your own sort function in any awk or just use shell (but that will be orders of magnitude slower execution):

```
$ while read -r -a old; do
    new=$(printf '%s\n' "${old[@]}" | sort -n | tr $'\n' ' ')
    printf '%s\n' "${new% }"
done < file
1 3 62 83
1 12 23 26 503
6 7 7 9 120
```